Proof that the increasing sequence of integer indices that define a subsequence is larger than the argument of the sequence
In my Real Analysis class started talking about subsequences and I have a doubt that goes as follows below.
In class we defined that, given a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, the sequence $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $y_n = x_{\alpha(n)}$ for some strictly increasing function $\alpha: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}.$
Basically I want to show that
$$\alpha(n) \geq n, \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
I tried doing it by induction, however, I'm not sure my proof is correct, specifically on the step highlightned by (1).
$\fbox{n=1}$
Because $\alpha:\mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is defined over the natural numbers and is strictly increasing $\alpha(1) \geq 1.$
Let $n > 1.$
$\fbox{Inductive Hypothesis} \ \alpha(n)\geq n.$
Thus we want to prove that $\alpha(n+1) \geq n + 1.$
Since our function is strictly increasing we have,
$$\exists \ k \in \mathbb{N}: \alpha(n+1)  = \alpha(n) + k.  \ (1)$$
Given that $k \in \mathbb{N},$
$$\alpha(n) + k \geq \alpha(n) + 1 \stackrel{\text{I.H.}}\geq n + 1.$$
$$\therefore \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}, \alpha(n) \geq n. \blacksquare$$
Can someone please check if it is correct, and if it isn't can someone please tell where I've made a mistake and maybe give me a tip.
Thank you!

We discourage "please check my answer" posts, as they lead only to "yes" or "no" answers and are unlikely to be useful to others in the future.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info for our policy on that.

I'm sorry I forgot to tag it as a solution-verification question

That was not the point of my comment.  My suggestion was to read the rules regarding solution verification questions. If you do that, you will discover that the question you have posted is not suitable here.  Questions asking "please check if my solution is correct" are not appropriate here, as explained there.  Please see that link for more details, and for what types of questions are appropriate here.

I edited my question. Is it more suitable now?

Your answer is fine. For a quicker proof, note that $\alpha(n+1) > \alpha(n)$ since $\alpha$ is a strictly increasing function. But by the inductive step: $\alpha(n) \ge n \implies \alpha(n+1) > n \implies \alpha(n+1) \ge n+1$ since $\alpha(n+1)$ is a positive integer.

I will also add an alternative method of proving which uses the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is well ordering.
Proof: Are know trivially that $\alpha(1)≥1$. Now suppose by contradiction that  $\alpha(n)<n$ for some $n$. Then by well ordering principle (and the fact that $n\neq 1$) there is  $N+1=\min \{ i\in \mathbb{N}:  \alpha(i)<i\}$ . Notice that then following inequalities holds: $$N+1>\alpha(N+1)>\alpha(N)≥N$$  This means there is a number $k$ (namely $\alpha(N+1)$) that is between  $N+1$ and $N$, which is contradiction, as  $N+1$ is a succesor of $N$. $\square$

Thank you! That is a very nice way of proving it.
